# How do I recode string data entries into numerical or decimal values?

Tags: python, recode

I want to recode data entries in an excel sheet that I will then use to perform other analyses on using python. Therefore, I want these string entries to be recoded into numerical or decimal values

This is what an entry looks like:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|16|Company Name||123 Address|Suite 123|City|ST|12345|Notes|Name|123 Anywhere Road||Notes|ST|12345|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|1234-1234-1|123456||||
```

I want the whole column to be transformed into numerical or decimal values. Any help?

Comment: You can split the string using the vertical bar. Then you can convert the entries you want using int() or float()

Comment: when you are talking about turning it into a numerical value, please specify the format that you want it to be

Comment: Do you think that it can be removed by the day's end?

Comment: Yunnosch- do you know if there are any updates to this situation?

Comment: Isathe, as far as I can tell, the problem you had ("outside" of the actual question) is solved. Let me know if there still is something troubling you.

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is not very clear, the following will get you going:

This code converts all the cells (split at vertical bar '|') that are all-digits, to numbers and saves to a list.

```
str="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|12|Company||123 Address|Suite 123|City|ST|12345|Notes|Name|123 Anywhere Road||Notes|ST|12345|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|1234-1234-1|123456||||"

cells=[int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in str.split('|')]
print (cells)
```

The output is:

```
['00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 12, 'Company', '', '123 Address', 'Suite 123', 'City', 'ST', 12345, 'Notes', 'Name', '
123 Anywhere Road', '', 'Notes', 'ST', 12345, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000
000000000', '1234-1234-1', 123456, '', '', '', '']
```

We can see that 12, 12345, 12345, 123456, being numeric have been printed without quotes.

If you need to convert numbers within other strings, slice the individual strings at spaces or hyphens for the conversion. In order to convert hex string to decimal number, you can provide `int()` with base parameter, 16 and it will convert it correctly, e.g.

```
int ("10", 16)
```

results correctly to decimal 16

Answer (score 1):

Arshad's answer can be applied to most of the columns and I think it's what you wanted in the first place. However, there are columns containing a name or something like this. In these cases, the common way to convert these strings into numerical values, would be encoding. For instance the column with the value of "Pantherx Rare" perhaps contains other names of this sort. To encode this, you must first clarify if there is an order between the values. If there is, ordinal encoders may come handy. If there isn't, one-hot encoding is what comes to my mind. These encoders can be found in scikit-learn library. Look at [this page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing).